# Callback on method for KO JS observable data after AJAX completion

Tags: magento2, ajax, knockoutjs, requirejs

I have a module that modifies the product prices on the catalog pages and needs to bypass the cache. My issue is that I've defined these classes and need to trigger their flush method once another class has completed it's AJAX request and has ensured that the data needed is added to the DOM. Everything works if I specify a timeout to execute the flush on a set interval (once the data is available) however I can not specify to flush all the product prices or even specify a specific product to flush such as product-item-123.flush(); What am I missing here? Am I not utilizing the correct context? How can I specify to call the flush method from another class once the ajax has completed? I've found references throughout the core such as

```
.trigger('contentUpdated');
```

Which seems to be some sort of event driven system. This will work too as all I need to know is when the AJAX request completes and I can handle the rest from there.

in final_price.phtml I instantiate a new ko class via

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "product-item-<?php echo $productId;?>": {
                        "component": "My_Module/js/price",
                        "template" : "My_Module/price",
                        "productId": <?php echo $productId?>,
                        "productprice":<?php echo $finalPriceModel->getValue()?>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My price.js looks like

```
define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
    'My_Module/js/helper/discount',
], function(ko, Component, priceUtils, discounthelper) {

return Component.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();
        this.discountedPrice = this.productprice;
        this.observe(['discountedPrice']);

        // this is what currently triggers the flush on all 
        // products after 10 seconds which is when the dom has 
        // the window.promoData set. Since it is called within the
        // same class it knows what product and template to update
        // but I need this to be triggered from the completion 
        // of the ajax request or an event that can be fired after 
        // the AJAX is complete that this class listens for. 
        setInterval(this.flush.bind(this), 10000);
    },
    calcPrice:function (){
        return '$'+priceUtils.formatPrice(discounthelper.renderDiscount(this.productprice._latestValue),{decimalSymbol:'.'},false);
    },
    flush: function(){
        if(window.promoData !== undefined) {
            this.discountedPrice(this.calcPrice());
        }
    }

});
});
```

My template file consists of

```
<p class="calcPrice" data-bind="text: discountedPrice"></p>
```

And my data model looks like

```
// This class is what handles the AJAX request on initialization 
// and sets the data in the DOM from the controller response.
define([
    'uiComponent'

], function(Component) {
"use strict";
return Component.extend ({
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();
        this.has_offers = this.hasOffer();
        console.log(this);
    },
    hasOffer:function () {
        $.ajax({
            url:'/autopromo/promotion/data',
            type:'GET'
        }).done(function (data) {
            window.promoData = JSON.parse(data.ad);

            // TODO: Call product price updates here
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: do you need to have one request for many products prices?

Comment: Each product should instantiate it's own javascript class. To eliminate the overhead on AJAX requests I would like to have one initial AJAX call on page load (as it does now) to get the customers session data related to an applied offer code and store the return to a value in the DOM. From there I just need a trigger to let me know that the AJAX request has completed and tell the classes to go ahead and calculate their prices.  It would be ideal to have one request to make this happen but if I need to keep track of the products and the page and call them individual I will.